# react + socket.io emits not going through - basic error

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, websocket, socket.io

There must be a simple mistake in my understanding of reactjs or socket.io. I have a server that sends "speed" values iterating from 2 to 5, and a client that receives them and displays them.

The issue:

**Expected behavior:** client displays numbers iterating from 1 to 5 every second and stops at 5. Client logs that it has received 4 messages with updated speed value (a new message every second)

**Actual behavior:** client displays a speed of 1. Client waits 4 seconds. Client displays a speed of 5 and, in that moment, logs having received the 4 messages with iterating speed from the server.

What is the issue? It's almost as if the server is sending all 4 speed messages at the same time.

Client code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {CircleGauge} from 'react-launch-gauge';
import io from 'socket.io-client';

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context)
        this.state = {
            speed: 1
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        const socket = io('http://localhost:5000');
        socket.on('data update', data => 
            this.setState( { speed: data }, 
                () => console.log("got the speed: " + this.state.speed)));
        socket.open();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p> The velocity received is: {this.state.speed}  </p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

Server Code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
import time

sendData = False;

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@socketio.on('connect')
def dataSent():
    print('they connected**********************************')
    for i in range(2,6):
        socketio.emit('data update', i)
        time.sleep(1)
        print(i)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, debug = True)
```

Comment: Not sure about the server code. Are you sure server waits for connection to be established before firing `data update` messages?

Comment: yes definitely, the socketio.on('connect') bind won't fire until the client has connected

Comment: On client: try removing the manual `socket.open();` and prevent polling `io('http://localhost:5000',{transports: ['websocket'], upgrade: false});`

Answer (score 1):

When the client requests the websocket connection via

```
const socket = io(‘ws://localhost:5000’);
```

it will have to wait until the connection is established first, before it can do anything with the message. The connection is established **only** when

```
@socketio.on(‘connect’)
def ...
```

is finished. So it looks like the client waits until all the emit is done, and then start reacting to the messages.

You probably need to make your for-loop asynchronous so that the server responds to the client about the connection first before it emits the data. For example, you can carve out the for-loop into a separate function and use flask’s background task:

```
@socketio.on(‘connect’)
def dataSent():
    print(‘...’)
    socketio.start_background_task(target=emitloop)

def emitloop():
    for i in range(2,6):
        socketio.emit(‘data update’, i)
        time.sleep(1)
```

(If flask is configured to use gevent for the background task, then you’ll need to install gevent or flask’s gevent plug-in.)

You might also try to use function based setState (i.e. passing a function to setState rather than the state object), because setState is asynchronous and react can combine them together otherwise.